# Even after 7 years of discharge, can a Bankruptcy and Consumer Proposal in Canada still be discovered?

Tags: ontario

My aunt in Ontario suffered serious psychiatric illnesses, but has now recovered. Her Bankruptcy was discharged in 2004 and Consumer Proposal in  2015. My aunt's Equifax and TransUnion credit reports no longer display them, but because the [Government of Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/financial-consumer-agency/services/credit-reports-score/information-credit-report.html)'s website doesn't specify if this information is expunged:

1) Can someone (e.g. a third-party Mortgage Agent) determined or intent to examine a person('s records) for bankruptcy or consumer proposal, still discover them somewhere now after discharge?

2) Is there any scintilla of a hint or trace or remnant of the Bankruptcy and Consumer Proposal? E.g., on the [Bankruptcy and Insolvency Records Search](https://strategis.ic.gc.ca/app/scr/bsf-osb/ins/login.html?lang=eng)?

> #### Consumer proposals
>
> A consumer proposal is a legal agreement set up by a licensed insolvency trustee. The trustee creates a proposal for your creditors where they agree to let you pay off a percentage of your debt.
>
> Equifax removes a consumer proposal from your credit report 3 years
>   after you've paid off all of the debts included in the proposal.
>
> TransUnion removes a consumer proposal from your credit report either:
>
> 3 years after you've paid off all of the debts included in the
>   proposal, or 6 years after you sign the proposal (whichever is sooner)
>
> #### Bankruptcy
>
> Generally, both Equifax and TransUnion remove a bankruptcy from your credit report 6 years after the date you're discharged.
>
> TransUnion removes a bankruptcy from your credit report 7 years after you're discharged in the following provinces:
>
> New Brunswick[,] Newfoundland and Labrador[,] Ontario[,] Prince Edward Island[,] Quebec
>
> If you declare bankruptcy more than once, then the bankruptcies
>   will appear on your credit report for 14 years.

Comment: It looks like it is available to the credit reporting agencies and whether it is reported or not will depend on their SOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Industry Canada through the Office of The Superintendent of Bankruptcy has an online Bankruptcy Records search database.  Searches currently cost $8 each.  If someone is intent on finding out if a person ever filed either bankruptcy or a consumer proposal, for $8 they can find out the basic details.  The Government is currently considering making searches free.  There is concern in the trustee community as to privacy issues.

We have made a video on this proposed change which will be part of our regular vlog next week.  You can take a sneak peak of the video by clicking on the title below.  Hope this helps you.

[BANKRUPTCY FILINGS FREE PUBLIC RECORDS: BANKRUPTCY FILINGS FREE PUBLIC RECORDS SEARCH BEGINS SOON](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDYBrnJW1O8&t=55s)